# Returning focus to first part of Delphi TDateTimePicker control

Tags: delphi, tdatetimepicker

After the focus leaves a TDateTimerPicker control and then at a later time returns to it, the control remembers which part (day, month or year) had the focus. Focus is returned to that part.

How can I force the focus back to the first per of the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force the control to forget which part had the focus you can change the DateFormat and then change it back again. So if it is set to dfShort set it to dfLong and then back to dfShort.

The trick is not to do this after the focus returns via the OnEnter event, but to do it before the focus is returned.

So the best place to do this is in the OnExit event.

```
procedure TForm1.DateTimePicker1Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin

  DateTimePicker1.DateFormat := dfLong;
  DateTimePicker1.DateFormat := dfShort;

end;
```

Comment: Thanks man. Working fine for me in Delphi 5. Exactly what I was looking for. It is worth to mention that all formatting of the control will be gone after that. So need to reformat it again.